# sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier manual inference for multiclass classification

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, linear-regression, multiclass-classification

I have trained a model for 3-class classification using sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier. Now I'm looking for a way for manual inference of the model. The problem here is that the model contains three pairs of [coef_, intercept_] so I don't understand how can I do a prediction in C++.

The code for training looks like in the sklearn example:

```
clf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3))
clf.fit(train_features, train_labels)
```

I tried to calculate values `coef_ * sample + intercept_` for each of the classes but didn't understand how to determine the class using that numbers.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea what you are trying to do. First, you would need to know the exact algorithm used by SGDClassifier and its exact implementation. Then you would need to reimplement that inference logic yourself (this may be far from trivial if they implement some optimizations or hacks to make it better). And don't forget that you are using the algorithm in a pipeline which you would also need to implement intro your logic with the exact values extracted from your fitted pipeline.

Comment: I thought that linear model means that in the end inference could be easily done by just applying the formula `coef_ * sample + intercept_` and comparing it to zero?
Is there any inference library for C++ to inference SGDClassifier models?

Comment: That is not the case. What you are describing is not a linear model but a simple linear regression. ex. SVM with a linear kernel is a linear model yet the inference is computed in a completely different manner. Moreover, you have a classifier which means that there is at least some kind of softmax function that normalizes the output. Even for simple logistic regression with 2 classes, you need to run the output through sigmoid function. I am sure it is doable but it may not be as easy as it may seem. I don't know whether there is a C++ adapter for sklearn.

Comment: Thanks Matus for the detailed answer!